# NodeJS error : Missing writing permission

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to setup express application generator and am running into the following error:
I am not able to understand why the writing access is being denied and so many errors are occurring.

```js
pragyasultania@pragyasultania-Vostro-3578:~/NodeJS/myapp$ npm install express-generator -g
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator' }
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

I am using Ubuntu operating system. Please guide me as to what settings of the operating system I should change so that these errors are overcomed!

Comment: have you checked permissions on folder in error ? User under which yoou are running it may not  have it. You may try to run `npm install express-generator -g`

Comment: the permissions of this particular folder was there for the current user. Removing -g worked for me!

Comment: applying sudo before the command also worked!